# Combined table filters in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a table and I want to apply 3 filters to it. 2 are selects and 1 is a search input. My only problem is that if I use the search input first then I select something in any of the other 2 filters the search input filter is ignored.

This is because I have the $(this).show(); command (line 6) inside the foreach that checks if every table row has the condition to be displayed.
However, I don't know how can I get rid of it and still make the script work. 
Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
    $("select#role_filter, select#type_filter").change(function() {
        var role = $("select#role_filter option:selected").text();
        var type = $("select#type_filter option:selected").text();
        var type_val = $("select#type_filter option:selected").val();
        $('#access-points > tbody > tr').each(function() {
            $(this).show();
            if (role != 'Display all') {
                var tooltips = $(this).find('td:first-child').attr('tooltips').split(', ');
                if (jQuery.inArray(role, tooltips) == -1) {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
                tooltips = [];
            }
            if (type != 'Display all') {
                var point_type = $(this).attr('point_type');
                if (point_type != type_val) {
                    $(this).hide();
                }
            }
        });
    });
    $("input#search_table").on("keyup", function() {
        var search = $(this).val();
        $('select#role_filter, select#type_filter').trigger('change');
        $('#access-points > tbody > tr').each(function() {
            if ($(this).css('display') != 'none') {
                if ($(this).attr('access_point').toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) === -1)
                    $(this).hide();
                else
                    $(this).show();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Don't use this `$("select#role_filter, select#type_filter")` use this: `$("#role_filter, #type_filter")`  The ID  is the fastest selector and unique and the others simply slow it down.

Comment: If you set up a demo, it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

IF I get your intent, it is to apply the filters AND the search.  Using your current logic for the "filters" it only shows if BOTH of those matches.  The most obvious way would be to get the items (table rows) then show them.

```
// returns a list of positive matches of the filters, 
// might be better to separate this into two functions
// one for each filter (and chain them)?
function checkFilters() {
  var role = $('#role_filter').find('option:selected').text();
  var type = $('#type_filter').find('option:selected').text();
  var type_val = $('#type_filter').find('option:selected').val();
  return $('#access-points').find('tbody>tr').filter(function() {
    var showme = true;
    if (role != 'Display all') {
      showme = jQuery.inArray(role, $(this).find('td').eq(0).attr('tooltips').split(', ')) == -1;
    }
    if (showme && type != 'Display all') {
      showme = $(this).attr('point_type') === type_val;
    }
    return showme;
  });
}

// returns a list of positive matches
function checkSearch(search) {
  var candidates = checkFilters();
  return candidates.filter(function() {
    return ($(this).attr('access_point').toLowerCase().indexOf(search) != -1);
  });
}

// BOTH these execute the same thing, just call it slightly different
// they both then show the filtered items matches
$("#role_filter, #type_filter").change(function() {
  checkSearch($("#search_table").val().toLowerCase()).show();
});
$("#search_table").on("keyup", function() {
  checkSearch($(this).val().toLowerCase()).show();
});
```